# Advanced numerical solution of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Show that the explicit Runge-Kutta scheme
\begin{equation} \frac {y_{n+1} -y_{n}}{h}= \frac{1}{2} [f(t,y_{n}) + f(t+h, y_{n}+hk_{1})]
\end{equation}
where $k_{1} = f(t,y_{n})$

applied to the equation $y'= y(1-y)$ has two spurious fixed points if $h>2$.

Briefy describe how you would investigate their stability.

=> my attempt so far
from $y'= y(1-y)$

$y'= 0$

$y=0$  or
$y=1$ which are the true fixed points.
after that i rearranged the Runge Kutta scheme
\begin{equation} \frac {y_{n+1} -y_{n}}{h}= \frac{1}{2} [f(t,y_{n}) + f(t+h, y_{n}+hk_{1})]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \frac{h}{2} [f(t,y_{n}) + f(t+h, y_{n}+hf(t,y_{n}))]
\end{equation}
i try to put the fixed points into above scheme and try to get two two Spurious fixed point for $y_{n}$ but i got struck.  for the stability to describe i need to get two Spurious fixed point first. but in general please help to describe stability too because this part i really get confuse. Anyone please help me, it will be really helpful for my other problems too if i got this answer correctly.

Comment: Since Runge-Kutta method generates a mapping, it's fixed points can be found by setting $y_{n+1} = y_{n}$. Just take some $y^{\ast}$ and plug it in instead of $y_n$ and $y_{n+1}$.

Comment: y*= 0 or 1,  what does stability say if h>2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for the step is missing some closing parantheses at the correct places. The correct form of the Heun resp. explicit trapezoidal method is

```
k1 = f(t,y)
k2 = f(t+h, y+h*k1)
ynext = y + h*(k1+k2)/2
```

With your given function this translates as
\begin{align}
    k1 &= y(1-y)\\
    k2 &= (y+hy(1-y))\,(1-y-hy(1-y))=y(1+h-hy)(1-y)(1-hy)\\
    y_+&=y+\tfrac12 hy(1-y)\bigl(1+(1+h-hy)(1-hy)\bigr)\\
       &=y+\tfrac12 hy(1-y)\bigl((1-hy+\tfrac12h)^2+1-\tfrac14h^2\bigr)
\end{align}

Thus for $h>2$ the last quadratic factor contributes the fixed points
\begin{align}
y&=\tfrac1h+\tfrac12\pm\sqrt{\tfrac14-\tfrac1{h^2}}
\end{align}